# how can I copy all cells in a datarow to session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, ado.net, foreach

```
foreach (has.has_actorRow actorrow in actortable.Rows) { 
                foreach(object actorcell in actorrow){
                //add all to session
                }
            }
```

gives me an error " has.has_actorrow" does not have a method 'getenumerator'"

Comment: How many rows are you hoping to copy to the session? Be careful, over-using session can be costly.

Comment: You can not use foreach loop bcz it seems from the error that datarow does not implement IEnumerable interface. Use for loop and copy each column one by one.

Answer (score 2):

probably you want to do `actorrow.Cells`

```
foreach (has.has_actorRow actorrow in actortable.Rows) { 
                foreach(object actorcell in actorrow.Cells){
                //add all to session
                }
            }
```

Comment: ok, glad you found the solution. I should've asked what has.has_actorRow inherited from.